# Om Next's query->ast and ast->query functions

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om

According to [Om Next's documentation](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Documentation-(om.next)#query-ast):

> #### query->ast
>
> ```
> (om.next/query->ast '[(:foo {:bar 1})])
> ```
>
> Given a query expression return the AST.
>
> #### ast->query
>
> ```
> (om.next/ast->query ast)
> ```
>
> Given a query expression AST, unparse it into a query expression.

**Question:** Why would one need these functions? That is, why would one need to directly manipulate a query abstract syntax tree (which I'm assuming are clojure maps that represent a query tree, along with some meta data) in om next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some scenarios where you need to manipulate the query ast directly. In remote parsing mode, the parser expects your read functions to return either {:remote-name true } or a (possibly modified) {:remote-name AST-node} (which comes in as :ast in env). Most often you'll have to modify the AST to restructure it or add some data.

Example 1:
You have a query: `[{:widget {:list [:name :created]}}]`
The `:widget` part is pure UI related, your server doesn't need to know it exists, it only cares/knows about the `:list`.
Basically you'll have to modify the AST in the parser:

```
(defmethod read :list
  [{:keys [ast query state]} key _ ]
  (let [st @state]
    {:value (om/db->tree query (get st key) st)
     :remote (assoc ast :query-root true)}))
```

If you use `om/process-roots`in your send function, it'll pick up the `:query-root` out of the ast and rewrite the query from `[{:widget {:list [:name :created]}}]` to `[{:list [:name :created]}]`.

Example 2:
Another example would be when you want to mutate something at a remote:

```
(defmethod mutate 'item/update
  [{:keys [state ast]} key {:keys [id title]}]
  {:remote (assoc ast :params {:data {:id id :title title })})
```

Here you need to explicitly tell Om to include the data you want to send in the AST. At your remote you then pick apart `:data` to update the title at the given id

Most of the time you won't use the functions you described in your questions directly. The `env` available in every method of the parser has the `ast` in it.

Comment: Just a note: You never used any of the functions that George is asking for :)

Comment: @Andre: this answer was still extremely informative! Also, he said most of the time these functions won't be used much in practice.

Comment: Does a `:remote` key in a reader function always have to have a query ast as its value? Or can it merely return a raw query (i.e.,  something of form`[ ... ]` using Datomic pull syntax)?

Comment: It's either an `ast` or just a boolean `true` to mark it for a certain remote. In the case of an `ast`, it has to be an `ast`, not a query. You could however use `(om/query->ast)` if you want to modify the query instead of an ast directly, before sending off that ast. Just keep in mind the end-result has to be a valid ast. Once you get the hang of it, modifying the ast from the env is just like drinking water or breathing air ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something I stumbled on, while trying to use Compassus:

Let's say you have a complex union/join query that includes parametric sub-queries. Something like this:

```
`[({:foo/info
        {:foo/header [:foo-id :name]
        :foo/details [:id :description :title]}} {:foo-id ~'?foo-id
                                                  :foo-desc ~'?foo-desc})]
```

Now let's say you want to set parameters so on the server you can parse it with om/parser and see those params as 3rd argument of `read` dispatch. Of course it's possible to write a function that would find all necessary parameters in the query and set the values. That's not easy though, and as I said - imagine your queries can be quite complex.

So what you can do - is to modify ast, ast includes `:children :params` key. So let's say the actual values for `:foo-id` and `:foo-desc` are in the state atom under `:route-params` key:

```
(defn set-ast-params [children params]
  "traverses given vector of `children' in an AST and sets `params`"
  (mapv
    (fn [c]
      (let [ks (clojure.set/intersection (-> params keys set) 
                                         (-> c :params keys set))]
        (update-in c [:params] #(merge % (select-keys params (vec ks))))))
    children))

(defmethod readf :foo/info
  [{:keys [state query ast] :as env} k params]
  (let [{:keys [route-params] :as st} @state
        ast' (-> ast 
                 (update :children #(set-ast-params % route-params))
                 om/ast->query
                 om.next.impl.parser/expr->ast)]
    {:value  (get st k)
    :remote ast'}))
```

So basically you are: 
- grabbing ast
- modifying it with actual values
you think maybe you can send it to server right then. Alas, no! Not yet. Thing is - when you do `{:remote ast}`, Om takes `:query` part of the ast, composes ast out of it and then sends it to the server. So you actually need to: turn your modified ast into query and then convert it back to ast again.

Notes:

- `set-ast-params` function in this example would only work for the first level (if you have nested parametrized queries - it won't work),
  *make it recursive - it's not difficult*
- there are two different ways to turn ast to query and vice-versa:

  ```
  (om/ast->query) ;; retrieves query from ast and sets the params based 
                  ;; of `:params` key of the ast, BUT. it modifies the query, 
                  ;; if you have a join query it takes only the first item in it. e.g. :
  [({:foo/foo [:id]
      :bar/bar [:id]} {:id ~'?id})]
  ;; will lose its `:bar` part 

  (om.next.impl.parser/ast->expr) ;; retrieves query from an ast, 
                                  ;; but doesn't set query params based on `:params` keys of the ast.

  ;; there are also
  (om/query->ast) ;; and
  (om.next.impl.parser/expr->ast)
  ```